# Avoid nested subscription in RXJS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following code:

```
someService.subscribeToChanges().subscribe(value => {
    const newValue = someArray.find(val => val.id === value.id)
    if (newValue) {
       if (value.status === 'someStatus') { 
          someArray.findIndex((a) => a.id === value.id)
          someArray.splice(index, 1);
       } else { 
          newValue.status = value.status;
       }
    } else { 
        if (value.someProp === 'abc') {
          someService.doSomeAsyncStuff().subscribe(data => {
            someService.handleData(data);
          });
        }
    }
 });
```

I would like to keep the same logic while avoiding the second subscribe.

This is the code that I tried

```
sub$ = someService.subscribeToChanges().pipe(switchMap(value => {
  const newValue = someArray.find(val => val.id === value.id)
  if (newValue) {  
       if (value.status === 'someStatus') { 
          someArray.findIndex((a) => a.id === value.id)
          someArray.splice(index, 1);
       } else { 
          newValue.status = value.status;
       }
  } else { 
    return iif(() => value.someProp === 'ABC', someService.doSomeAsyncStuff);
  }
}));

sub$.subscribe(data => someService.handleData(data))
```

This works if the `iif` condition is true, but if it is false, it just stops the whole stream, while I want it to keep streaming.

Comment: Should it be `return doSomeStuff();`?

Comment: @Andrew No, it doesnt have to. Those are just some operations done on the side.

Comment: The question is unclear and missing information. If `doSomeStuff` returns void than this will error if `newValue` is truthy

Comment: @AndrewAllen I changed the code to show what `doSomeStuff` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split them into three conditions

```
sub$ = someService.subscribeToChanges().pipe(switchMap(value => {
 const newValue = someArray.find(val => val.id === value.id)
 if (newValue) {
   if (value.status === 'someStatus') { 
      someArray.findIndex((a) => a.id === value.id)
      someArray.splice(index, 1);
   } else { 
      newValue.status = value.status;
   }
 return of(value); 
 }

    if(value.someProp === 'ABC')
      return someService.doSomeStuff()

    return of(value)
  })
)
```

Comment: Having side effects within a switchmap/pipe in general is not a good practice. In small projects it will work for sure but the larger your project gets the more downsides it has.

Comment: Not sure about the intention of doSomeStuff here and whether it is a side effect, need more clarification.

Comment: Yes the thing is that `doSomeStuff()` is not async. It just modifies some array.

Comment: I wrapped it with of() so it will execute and feed the switchMap with an observable, and depends what you want this sync function to return you can do of(dosomestuff()).pipe(mapTo(...))

Comment: @FanCheung, but doSomeStuff is not async. I updated my code with the what's in doSomeStuff.

Comment: updated the code. if it is just some array operation you can just return of(..) whatever that you want to pass down stream.

Comment: Why are we returning `    return of(value)` again at the end?

Comment: Whatever you want to return if the first condition is met, of(value) is a simple observable wrapped value. The technique here is what we call 'early return' so the code can be cleaner 
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement

Comment: @FanCheung, yes for the first condition I understand, but why is it needed for a third condition?

Comment: Third condition is to fix your bug when `value.someProp === 'ABC'` is false, and you still get the observable to return something so it won't hang there

Comment: When I try to return `of(value)` there, I get a type error, can I return `of(null)` ?

Comment: You can if that fits your logic needs. you can even just return of()

Comment: hmm, does it actually mean that in my `iif` solution everything would have worked if I had simply put `empty()` for example in the second condition of the `iif`?

Comment: yes you are correct, but iff() operator is rarely use it is simply cleaner and easier to use normal if and return whether value or observable

Answer (score 0):

Nested subscriptions are an [antipattern](https://www.thinktecture.com/de/angular/rxjs-antipattern-1-nested-subs/) in rxjs. So its good that you try to avoid it. I would recommend you still using two subscriptions but not nested. Because you have to different side effects (someService.handleData and doSomeStuff)

**Create your subscribeTochanges id with someArray id comparator for reuse reasons**

```
const subscribeToChangesIdEqualsSomeArrayId$ = someService.subscribeToChanges().pipe(
  map(value => someArray.find(val => val.id === value.id)
);
```

**Create your doSomeStuff Observable**

```
const doSomeStuff$ = subscribeToChangesIdEqualsSomeArrayId$.pipe(
  filter(newValue => newValue)
);
```

**Create your handleData Observable**

```
const handleData$ = combineLatest([
  subscribeToChangesIdEqualsSomeArrayId$,
  someService.subscribeToChanges()
]).pipe(
  filter(([newValue, value]) => !newValue && value.someProp === 'abc'),
  switchMap(() => someService.doSomeStuff())
);
```

**Final usage**

```
doSomeStuff$.subscribe(() => doSomeStuff());
handleData$.subscribe(data => someService.handleData(data));
```

*FYI: I used all the outer and inner (from pipe perspective) variable names you used in your question. I would maybe adjust them for the sake of reading :)*

Comment: Is there anyway to do the same without changing the `someArray` to an observable? Because that would require so many changes in the app.

Comment: Yes of course it's much more easy then. Answer is updated. Now you do not need to give in the array as an observable. You can use it directly in the subscribeToChangesIdEqualsSomeArrayId$ observable as an sideeffect. All belongs to you.

Answer (score -1):

It's always much better to keep all logic in a single chain, so you can do it for example like this. Since you don't need `newValue` further down the chain it's pretty simple:

```
someService.subscribeToChanges()
  .pipe(
    switchMap(value => {
      const newValue = someArray.find(val => val.id === value.id);
      if (!newValue && value.someProp === 'abc') {
        return someService.doSomeStuff();
      }
      return of(undefined);
    }),
  )
  .subscribe(data => {
    if (data === undefined) { // When data is set means we ran the second Observable
      doSomeStuff();
    } else {
      someService.handleData(data);
    }
  });
```

If for `someService.doSomeStuff()` is `undefined` a valid response then I'd wrap its response with some object like `{ response: data }` so you'll always know where it came from.

Try to avoid making multiple subscriptions until it's really necessary because that brings  more things you have to be aware of (like order of subscriptions, sharing Observables and so on) and it's always easier to read RxJS chains in top-down order like it was synchronous code.

Comment: the thing is that I need that data for `doSomeStuff` I have updated my code to show what I am doing with that data. Can you please check?

Comment: I can't see where you do that in your example

Comment: I replaced `doSomeStuff` with equivalent code, inside the first `if` you can see that it is using for example `newValue.status = value.status;` which is not available in the `subscribe` in your code.

Comment: I'm too confused to be honest